# Can hollandaise be made with frozen lemon juice?

Tags: eggs, sauce, lemon-juice, hollandaise

In my other question -- [Are there any reasonable substitutes for lemon juice?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1045/60) -- I learned a cool technique to preserve lemon juice by freezing it in an ice tray. I'm considering making a hollandaise, and the only lemon juice I have available is frozen. Will this affect my hollandaise? Could it increase the chances of splitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be absolutely fine, whether you make the sauce in the classic way by cooking the yolks with the lemon juice, or with one of the variations where the lemon juice is added only at the end. I would, of course, defrost it first, rather than add a whole ice cube of lemon juice to the pan.

Comment: Yep, it worked just fine.